# Two setter/getter for the same member varaible

Tags: c#, properties

I have private member variable in C# class like this:

```
class foo{
    private byte bar;
}
```

I want to make two(or more) setter/getter like this:

```
class foo{
    private byte bar;

    public int Bar{
        get{return (int)bar;}
        set{bar=(byte)bar;}
    }    

    public string Bar{
        get{return "Nothing";}
        set{bar=0;}
    }
}
```

Is this possible? or any other equivalent pattern ?

Comment: Not in [tag:C#]. You will get compilation error

Comment: They will have to have different names.

Comment: I did not try it because it seems not logical it is impossible to deduct the type when getting. so I was asking for way to make it possible

Comment: You can learn more about properties here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288470(v=vs.71).aspx and here http://www.dotnetperls.com/property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Technically, you can *mimic* such a behaviour via *implicit operators*:

```
  public struct Bar {
    internal Bar(Byte value) {
      Value = value;
    }

    internal Bar(String value) {
      if (String.Equals(value, "Nothing", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        Value = 0;
      else
        Value = Byte.Parse(value);
    }

    public Byte Value {
      get;
      private set;
    }

    public override string ToString() {
      return Value == 0 ? "Nothing" : Value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator Byte (Bar value) {
      return value.Value;
    }

    public static implicit operator String(Bar value) {
      return value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator Bar(Byte value) {
      return new Bar(value);
    }

    public static implicit operator Bar(String value) {
      return new Bar(value);
    }
  }

  class Foo {
    private Bar m_Bar;

    public Bar Bar {
      get {
        return m_Bar;
      }
      set {
        m_Bar = value;
      }
    }
  }
```

Now, let's have fun:

```
  Foo foo = new Foo();

  foo.Bar = 123;
  foo.Bar = "Nothing";

  String test = foo.Bar;
  Byte testByte = foo.Bar;
```

However, even if you *can* do this you´d better *not* do and just declare two properties with different names.

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not possible.  The closest thing you can do is possibly something like this:

```
class foo
{
    private byte bar;

    public int BarAsInt
    {
        get { return Convert.ToInt32(bar); }
        set { bar = Convert.ToByte(value); }
    }

    public string BarAsString
    {
        get { return bar.ToString(); }
        set { bar = byte.Parse(value); }
    }
}
```

Of course, this solution isn't complete, because you could run into errors trying to convert back and forth if the values are not compatible (e.g. converting a string "hello" to byte, or converting integer 4,235 to byte).  You'd most likely want to make these methods instead with proper validation, possibly throwing an exception if the conversions fail.

Comment: I see. Thanks for time!

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in C# as you see in the picture below:

[image]

Your program won't even compile. So you'll need to give the second property another name.